# Magento quick search showing no results, advanced search does work

Tags: magento-1.9, php, catalogsearch, phtml

I have a very strange problem with a customer.

The quicksearch of magento (form.mini) does not show any results. When I switch to the advanced search, the search results does appear correctly.

What I've done so far:

- Checked all the product attributes if they are searchable;
- Reindexed the complete shop;
- Flushed all the caches;
- truncated catalogsearch.fulltext;
- Switched to the default magento theme

You can check it at this URL https://www.compel.nl

The advanced search is over here: https://www.compel.nl/catalogsearch/advanced/

Comment: Quick search worked for me: https://www.compel.nl/supplies.html?q=hp+cn045ae. This gave me the right result too. Is it you already fixed?

Comment: Please check again. The results do not work.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the problem. Your quick search is only searching the current page, not the entire catalogue. This means your search function must have been modified or overridden by custom or third party extension.

Comment: And again, site is acting very differently. Now, it goes searching entire catalog, but doesn't give the result. See the url I supplied at first comment. Cannot tell what is wrong. You will need to check if there are any extension playing the role.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, I've cleared all the products and now I have the products back online. Could you have a look again?

Comment: Sorry, cannot tell what's happening. You will need to check which extension (or anything else) is playing the role. By default, Magento gives you search results.

Comment: Ok, I've found it! Thanks Adarsh, it looks like blastlucene search is having a conflict with my search results. I've disabled the module and now it's working like expected.